# Display that replaces previous values

Tags: gui-construction, button

Is it possible to make some function like `Print` but one that replaces its previous result with a new value instead of producing a new one?

For example, let's use this code:

```
Button[
  "shortest tour", 
  Print[b = a[[Last[FindShortestTour[a]]]]], 
  Method -> "Queued"]
```

When I press this button many times it gives me new results instead of replacing the old one.

Comment: Please give an example of the output you seek.  What code have you tried?

Comment: Perhaps `Monitor` can be made to do what you want?

Comment: I try code Print[]

Comment: `PrintTemporary`? https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PrintTemporary.html

Comment: PrintTemporary doesnt give me any value. I want just 1 value that keep replacing each time I press shift+enter

Comment: Please add detail to the question,  at the moment answering entails too much guesswork. Perhaps  `Dynamic` is what you want,  but that's more guessing.

Comment: it is very simple question. I dont know which part you dont understand. For example lets use this code: Button["shortest tour", 
 Print[b = a[[Last[FindShortestTour[a]]]]], Method -> "Queued"]

When I press this button many times it gives me new results instead of replacing the old one.

Comment: Please put this into the question, in a way that makes reproduction of your example simple (i.e. by providing working code).

Answer (score 1):

Forget about trying to change the behavior of `Print`. All you need is a dynamic global variable to display the value you want to see.

```
Dynamic[random]
```

> `42`

```
Button["Random Integer", random = RandomInteger[99]]
```

[image: button]

Each time you click on the button you will see a new random integer. You should have no trouble adopting this idea to your application.